# Wrapping for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, iterable

I want to wrap the functionality of for loop so it would be more intuitive to use it. In my case, I have to parse xml file looks like this:

```
<instance id="line-n.w8_047:15696:">
    <answer instance="line-n.w8_047:15696:" senseid="product" />
    <context> context1 </context>
</instance>

<instance id="line-n.w8_088:12441:">
    <answer instance="line-n.w8_088:12441:" senseid="product" />
    <context> another context</context>
</instance>
```

I wrote a class for `Instance` like this:

```
class Instance:
    def __init__(self, id, answer, context):
        self.id = id
        self.answer = answer
        self.context = context
```

I wrote the next function to enumerate the instances:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def enum_instances(file_path, action):
    for instance_xml in ET.parse(file_path).getroot().find('lexelt'):
        action(Instance(
            instance_xml.attrib['id'],
            instance_xml.find('answer').attrib['senseid'],
            instance_xml.find('context').text)
        )
```

The `action` parameter is a callback to do some action with the `Instance`, like this:

```
enum_instances('/path/to/xml', lambda instance: print(instance.context))
```

but it looks a bit odd, I would like it be more intuitive, like this:

```
for instance in enum_instances(file_path):
    print(instance.context)
```

what is the best way to implement that 'iterable' function?
Thanks

Comment: So why not do just what you want then? Don't call action... instead... `yield` the instance...

Comment: BTW, that XML file is not XML. There must be a single root.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph You right, there is a root and a messy structure for my xml, but I put only the relevant part for the question

Answer (score 3):

Generators for the win, in this case. Something like

```
def enum_instances(file_path):
    for instance_xml in ET.parse(file_path).getroot().find('lexelt'):
        yield Instance(
            instance_xml.attrib['id'],
            instance_xml.find('answer').attrib['senseid'],
            instance_xml.find('context').text)
```

Then you can say exactly what you required:

```
for instance in enum_instances(file_path):
    print(instance.context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a callable to your function, make it yield an `Instance`, then you can get the behaviour you want, eg:

```
def enum_instances(file_path, action=None):
    for instance_xml in ET.parse(file_path).getroot().find('lexelt'):
        instance = Instance(
            instance_xml.attrib['id'],
            instance_xml.find('answer').attrib['senseid'],
            instance_xml.find('context').text)
        if action is not None:
            instance = action(instance)
        yield instance
```

In this case - I've defaulted `action` to `None`, but it leaves you room to pass a function to mutate the `instance` somehow before `yield`ing it if required.

Then:

```
for instance in enum_instances('some_file_path'):
    print(instance.context)
```

Comment: I think you just beat me to it - do you have an extra paren after `text)` on the last line?